# c# class - make function or method call and pass control

Tags: c#, methods

I'm not sure if my title is really correct.  I've looked around and searched but not found anything so please forgive me if my problem has been answered already.

What I would like to do is call a function but not have to come back to the calling line of code. e.g

```
public static void temp(obj) {
   switch (obj.id) {
     case "1" :
       if(blah) {
         obj.id = "2";
         temp(obj);
       }
       break;
     case "2" :
       obj.response = "done";
       break;
   }
}
```

so basically I dont want to eventually come back to my temp(obj) in the first case and fully pass control.  Does this make sense, is it even possible and my architecture is all wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: **No**, this does not make sense. You are making recursive calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand the question:

You've got a function `Foo()`, which calls function `Bar()`. (I wanted to remove the recursion you had in your example for simplicity, please correct me if that was important.) When function `Bar()` returns, you want control to pass not back to `Foo()`, but to Foo's caller?

This is probably possible in lower-level languages, like C, by hacking the stack and not placing `Foo()`'s return address there, so that when `Bar()` tried to return, it would jump to Foo's caller instead.

However, in C#, no. The call stack is a stack, and control will pass back in order. The only thing you can do would be to put a `return` statement after each call to `Bar()`.

**Edit:**

"recursive calls without them being recursive"

How about this:

```
bool doItAgain = true;
while(doItAgain)
{
    doItAgain = false;

    // process, with your switch statement or whatever.

    if(...)
    {
        doItAgain = true;
        continue; // if necessary, skip any code after this statement. May not be necessary if you have things set up right.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply David.  I kind of wanted recursive calls without them being recursive.  Even typing it out now kind of makes it obvious that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If this were C++, you could eliminate the `break` and let the case "1" fall through, but this is not allowed in C# switch statements.

```
public static void temp(obj) {
   if (obj.id == "1") {
      obj.id = "2";
      temp(obj);
   }

   if (obj.id == "2")
       obj.response = "done";
}
```

Do you need the recursive call? This code retains your recursive call and sets obj.response to "done" after changing obj.id to "2". However, obj.response is set twice because of the recursive call. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am basically implementing a scorm sequencing module.  the obj represents a sequence class with data and response strings which get changed every time the object is passed through the sequencing function.  I guessed what I wanted wasn't possible but wanted to check first.  Thanks for your time, I will re-think my structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly intend, but it sounds like a callback to me. Here is one possible example:

```
void DoSome()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate { RunMe(); ReturnTo(); }));
}

void RunMe() { }

void ReturnTo() { }
```

You start in DoSome() and continue, when RunMe is finished ReturnMe is called.

Comment: Sorry I think i spoke prematurely. After testing a bit I realised I do need the recursion.  I need to pass the changed object back into the function and instead of not giving up control I need to give it full control and drop the original thread.  This is cool though and have implemented it else where lol.

Comment: Since you use an object - that is a reference type - you could pass it as parameter to RunMe aswell as to ReturnTo. ReturnTo could perform a check (recursion exit) and call RunMe again with the changed object...